# Is it possible to limit Google Maps to display only a given country?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to limit Google Maps to display only a given country?

e.g. I'd only like the UK to be visible in a huge sea of blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using overlays, [this](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_texas.html) is the closest example I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no" (as they have bitmap images of their maps, and would need to re-render to exclude mainland Europe, etc.) - you could build your own set of tiles using [Open Street Map](http://www.OpenStreetMap.org/) data, to achieve the same thing.

Comment: OK, thanks Rowland. I wonder if you could add an opaque overlay to achieve the same effect though?

Comment: You could, but the real map would show through temporarily when you move/zoom/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript you can limit the viewport, but it's not possible to actually get rid of the images of the other countries.